# Countdown Timer downloaded from Windows App store

Tags: powershell, app-store

does anyone know a windows countdown timer app, that can be pre configured using a powershell script or cmd. So that when the app launches from start up, the countdown will use that onetime pre-set profile.

Example script profile has a due date . When I turn on my computer it will automatically use that profile configure for countdown.

Answer (score 0):

First, questions:

- Why an app from the store?
- Do you expect other people to use or interact with this?
- Is something supposed to happen when it's done counting down?

**An example:**

Create a powershell script with:

```
sleep -seconds 300
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Time's up!")
```

Then create a scheduled task to run it at logon

Comment: Count down timer should be a system app, that can not be shutdown via task manager or powershell kill -processname.  All efforts to try and do so should be logged

Comment: @Glen, what happens when the time is up. They get logged off?

Comment: The purpose is to have a visible clock but not distracting, the clock only starts when a user starts taking the test which is in onenote, when the time runs out it closes the exam or gives warning for last five minutes or so. However the problem with powershell is student can also edit or close the script

Comment: In theory it would be nice to change the taskbar in lower right into a count down timer

hoping there a way to have a system app that exam comes with an encrypted config file that uploads the timer variables

Comment: @Glen Are the computers owned and managed by you?

Comment: They are virtual machine powered with Azure

Comment: @Glen do you already have a way to start a powershell script once the student begins the quiz?

Comment: Thank you for taking some time looking into these, I may have found an exe app, that I can modify the config. And find a way to run a script to install and import that config file with my virtual machines on start up